# I am creating my first R package but cant seem to get a function to output a file into the rstudio enviroment

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools, r-package

I am creating my first R package. One of the functions will be taking in a vcf file and outputing it formatted into the R env for further use. Here's the code below!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrUpC.png)

After I install the package this is what I get:

```
> devtools::install()
── R CMD build ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\raymu\OneDrive\Documents\R\LoF\myfirstpackage/DESCRIPTION' ...
─  preparing 'myfirstpackage':
E  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
   Malformed maintainer field.
   
   See section 'The DESCRIPTION file' in the 'Writing R Extensions'
   manual.
Error in `(function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE, …`:
! System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed
---
Exit status: 1
stdout & stderr: <printed>
---
```

When I try to execute the function on a test vcf file there is no error but doesn't make anything in the environment

I tried devtools::check and got this but am unsure what it means

```
> devtools::check()
══ Documenting ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
ℹ Updating myfirstpackage documentation
ℹ Loading myfirstpackage
Warning: Skipping NAMESPACE
✖ It already exists and was not generated by roxygen2.

══ Building ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Setting env vars:
• CFLAGS    : -Wall -pedantic
• CXXFLAGS  : -Wall -pedantic
• CXX11FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic
• CXX14FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic
• CXX17FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic
• CXX20FLAGS: -Wall -pedantic
── R CMD build ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\raymu\OneDrive\Documents\R\LoF\myfirstpackage/DESCRIPTION' (405ms)
─  preparing 'myfirstpackage':
E  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
   Malformed maintainer field.
   
   See section 'The DESCRIPTION file' in the 'Writing R Extensions'
   manual.
Error in `(function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE, …`:
! System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed
---
Exit status: 1
stdout & stderr: <printed>
---
Type .Last.error to see the more details.
> .Last.error
<system_command_status_error/rlib_error_3_0/rlib_error/error>
Error in `(function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE, …`:
! System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed
---
Exit status: 1
stdout & stderr: <printed>
---
Backtrace:
 1. devtools::check()
 2. withr::with_envvar(pkgbuild::compiler_flags(FALSE), action = "prefix", …
 3. base::force(code)
 4. pkgbuild::build(pkg$path, tempdir(), args = build_args, quiet = quiet, …
 5. withr::with_temp_libpaths(rcmd_build_tools(options$cmd, c(options$path, …
 6. base::force(code)
 7. pkgbuild::rcmd_build_tools(options$cmd, c(options$path, options$args), …
 8. pkgbuild::with_build_tools({ …
 9. withr::with_path(rtools_path(), code)
10. base::force(code)
11. base::withCallingHandlers(callr::rcmd_safe(..., env = env, spinner = FALSE, …
12. callr::rcmd_safe(..., env = env, spinner = FALSE, show = FALSE, …
13. callr:::run_r(options)
14. base::with(options, with_envvar(env, do.call(processx::run, c(list(bin, …
15. base::with.default(options, with_envvar(env, do.call(processx::run, …
16. base::eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
17. base::eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
18. callr:::with_envvar(env, do.call(processx::run, c(list(bin, args = real_cmdargs, …
19. base::force(code)
20. base::do.call(processx::run, c(list(bin, args = real_cmdargs, stdout_line_callback = real_callback(stdout), …
21. (function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE, …
22. base::throw(new_process_error(res, call = sys.call(), echo = echo, …
23. | base::signalCondition(cond)
24. (function (e) …
25. asNamespace("callr")$err$throw(e)
```

I am expecting a formatted table in the Rstudio environment that can be utilized further by the user.
I have a separate script that I have developed and works great but want to transform it into a package for ease of use and deployment for my thesis research
Please let me know if there is any other info that I missed.

Comment: You should separate 'writing the function' from 'putting a function into a package'.  It looks like your function itself isn't doing what you want, so you should post a question with the code for you function (not an image) and leave out all of the package stuff.  My guess is that your function is creating a file in R's current working directory, but you want the output put into the global environment.

Comment: As to the package errors, your DESCRIPTION field has a malformed maintainer field.  Look up what it should look like, or use a template, or post it in a separate question.  Also, you should use `devtools::document()` to create the NAMESPACE, don't make it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the `save` line at the end of your function.  Put `return(tmp_vcf_data)` or even simply `tmp_vcf_data` as the last line of your function.  This way your function will return your formatted vcf file.

Then call your function and assign the output to an object.  For example `output <- load_vcf(inline)`.